# Yellow sidebar markup is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, sidebar

Your yellow sidebar has a slight markup issue. You have a loop on the `<ul>` of your lists, when it [should be on the `<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).

Here's the markup for that component, stripped of attributes and inner text for readability.

```html
<div>
   <div></div>
   <ul> <!-- The looping should be on the <li></li> element, not the <ul></ul> -->
      <li>
         <div>
            <a>
               <svg>
                  <path></path>
               </svg>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a></a>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul> <!-- See? -->
   <ul>
      <li>
         <div>
            <a>
               <svg>
                  <path></path>
               </svg>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div>
            <a></a>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've fixed this and also have taken the opportunity to fix it up a bit visually as well by removing the unnecessary lines between each item. This also helps a lot with accessibility for folks using screen readers. Thanks for the report!